# Getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on Protractor Typescript Automation Framework

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor, ui-automation

Here's the structure of my UI automation framework. It is Typescript compiling to Protractor.

**3 Specs:**

Each Import from page objects, application helpers and framework helpers

**Page objects:**
Import functions from helper.
Import functions from application helper. //Commenting this works wonders and doesn't throw errors

**Framework Helper functions:**
Just functions.

**Application Helper functions:**
Import functions from helper.

I read that if there are too many functions this will happen. But this is necessary for my framework to not bloat into messy unmanageable code.

How to avoid this? What are the best practices?

Error:

```
× encountered a declaration exception
      - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Additionally with such a complex framework,

```
debugger;
```

just doesn't work.

**Sample Code:**

```
describe('My app', () => {
    debugger;
    let login = new LoginPage(),//Has a few functions
        dashboard = new DashboardPage(); //Has a few functions
    // myApp: myAppHelper = new myAppHelper();//Has a few functions. Called in all the page object files. If commented everywhere except 1 then works fine.

    //There are just 3 spec files and 3 page objects. No infinite loops anywhere and everything is quite straightforward.

    beforeEach(async () => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });
    afterEach(async () => {
        await console.log("Step completed.")
    });


    it('open all admin pages', async () => {
        try {
            browser.pause();
            // await myApp.login();
            await login.loginToMyApp('UserID', 'Password');
            await browser.sleep(5000);
            // await dashboard.openAdminPurposes();
            await browser.sleep(5000);
            // await dashboard.openAdminmyAppProcesses();
            await browser.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("Open admin pages failed." + error);
        }
    });
```

**Application Helper**

```
/**
 * A library of reusable functions that can be used across the abc.
 * Do NOT add any functions that are related to the automation framework.
 */
import { browser, by, WebElement, element } from 'protractor';
import { Helper } from './helper';
import { DashboardPage } from './page-objects/abc/dashboard-page';


export class myAppHelper {
    helper: Helper = new Helper();
    dashboardPage: DashboardPage = new DashboardPage();
    currentEnvironment: string = "beta";
    serverURL: string = this.setServerURL(this.currentEnvironment);
    subSt: string = "/v3/abc/view/";
    adminSt: string = "/v3/abc/admin/";
    URL: string = this.serverURL;

    setServerURL(env: string): string {
        if (env.toLowerCase() == "beta") {
            return this.serverURL = "https://beta-abcde.abc.com";
        }
        else {
            return this.serverURL = "https://abcde.abc.com";
        }
    }

    async login(): Promise<void> {
        await browser.get(this.URL);
    }

    async gotoDashboard(): Promise<void> {
        await browser.get(this.URL + this.subSt + "dashboard");
        await this.helper.compareText(this.dashboardPage.dashboardHeader, "Dashboard");
    }

    async gotoProjectsList(): Promise<void> {
        await browser.get(this.URL + this.subSt + "projects");
    }

    //Admin Pages
    async gotoAdminPurposes(): Promise<void> {
        await browser.get(this.URL + this.adminSt + "purposes");
    }

    }

    //The rest of the functions are application specific but you get the idea.
}
```

**Helper**

```
/**
 * A library of reusable functions that can be used across the framework.
 * Do NOT add any functions that are project/module specific.
 */
import { browser, WebElement } from 'protractor';


export class Helper {
    async enterText(aelement: WebElement, textToEnter: string): Promise<void> {
        await browser.sleep(1000);
        await aelement.sendKeys(textToEnter);
    }

    async click(aelement: WebElement): Promise<void> {

        try {
            await browser.sleep(1500);
            await aelement.click();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("Error in click: " + error);
        }
    }

    async readText(element: WebElement): Promise<string> {

        var elementText = await element.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log("ReadText is : " + text);
            return text;
        });
        return elementText;
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing all pageObjects for each test? If so is this required? Is there a possibility that there is a single function that is causing this problem, such as one looping over a huge number of iterations?

Comment: Yes. You are right. So when I comment the object created for a helper function, everything works fine. But I need them. I just don't know how to use them without running into the above problem.

Comment: Are you referring to the framework helper functions or application helper functions? I assume these are separate files?

Comment: By framework, are you asking TS? I have a helpers file for the automation framework(approx 10 functions for like click, select dropdown, check if element is present, etc) and I have another project/application helper (approx 10 functions for functions like check if all 10 checkboxes are displayed, check if 4 buttons are displayed, etc.) Both are separate files.

Comment: Ok, based on that it's highly unlikely you have too many functions. I have some page objects with 50+ methods which work just fine. Could you post an example of the structure of one of those helper files with a few sample functions?

Comment: I have added some sample code for your reference. :) 50 is ideal. I am nowhere near, which is what makes me wonder.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, I was actually looking for some of the sample code from myAppHelper as that is likely where the issue is. Also, the debugger keyword will not work so you can comment that line out. I cannot recall why exactly but it is a known issue

Comment: Spot on. debugger; doesn't work in VSCode. Do you know why? Ok, I will paste the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189012/discussion-between-williamtell-and-dublindev).

Comment: Not sure if you have seen it yet but I did respond in the chat with you william

Comment: Thanks for the help @DublinDev The error got resolved on its own when I checked out the same project in a different location. I have no idea how it got resolved. The same project in the previous location is still throwing the error. Weird. Sometimes, just copy pasting or checking out the same project in a different place just helps :)

Comment: Ha those weird errors are by far the most frustrating to debug. Glad you got it sorted anyway!

Comment: You bet. Thanks again. It is because of people like you and the help that you provide to the community, I keep coming back and return the favour to others. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

The error got resolved on its own when I checked out the same project in a different location. I have no idea how it got resolved. The same project in the previous location is still throwing the error. Weird. Sometimes, just copy pasting or checking out the same project in a different place just helps :)